# WP7 any way to get the pic of the contact

Tags: windows-phone-7

i look at the list of choosers for windows phone 7 and i miss one where i can read the avatar-pic fo the contact. am i missing something here or is this just not possible yet?

thx
sargola

Answer (score 1):

This isn't possible through the phone SDK at the moment.

What is exposed is being able to retrieve the email address or the phone number from a chooser. Details on that here for reference.

[How to: Use Choosers for Windows Phone](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff769543%28v=VS.92%29.aspx)